# Convert HH:mm:ss format to java.util.Date format?

Tags: jquery, hibernate, spring-mvc, datetime

i am doing one application based on spring,hibernate. I need a requirement i.e. i have one field that accepts only Time(not date) HH:mm:ss, i want this field have to bind to dto. but i am getting folloing exception :

```
Field error in object 'reservation' on field 'arrivaltime': rejected value [21:00:3]; codes  
[typeMismatch.reservation.arrivaltime,typeMismatch.arrivaltime,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [reservation.arrivaltime,arrivaltime]; arguments []; default message [arrivaltime]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'arrivaltime'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'arrivaltime': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]] with root cause
org.springframework.validation.BindException:org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'reservation' on field 'arrivaltime': rejected value [21:00:3]; codes [typeMismatch.reservation.arrivaltime,typeMismatch.arrivaltime,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [reservation.arrivaltime,arrivaltime]; arguments []; default message [arrivaltime]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'arrivaltime'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'arrivaltime': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I am selecting the time by JQuery plugin.

```
jq('#arrivaltime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        format:'H:i:j',
        step:60
    });
```

my field in DTO class like this :

```
@Column(name = "booking_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date booking_date;
```

I want only Time format to bind that field. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can hint the expected date pattern to the framework using the [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) and its [pattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) attribute. The following should work

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "booking_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date booking_date;
```

Comment: well, `DataTimeFormat` annotation is a way to go, so without further details, I'm not sure what exactly is causing your issue. Do note one thing,  your exception mentions the `arrivaltime` property, not the `booking_date` property.